# Vue, Mirroring the elements

Tags: javascript, algorithm, vue.js

There are two teams, each has a logo and name, and for the first team, we display the logo, and then the name, and for the second, the name, and then the logo. I wanted to put the logo and name in the component, and handle this situation like this :

```
<div class="team_container">
    <template v-if="isTeam1Flag">
        <img :src="teamLogoSrc" alt="Logo Team 1">
        <span >Team 1</span>
    </template>
    <template v-else>
        <span >Team 1</span>
        <img :src="teamLogoSrc" alt="Logo Team 1">
    </template>
</div>
```

Can you tell me if there is a better solution for this task? In each branch code, in fact, the same logic, the difference is only in the order of the elements.

Comment: What is the reason for the elements to be swapped around? Potentially this would be better handled by CSS so that the markup isn't made inconsistent.

Comment: Yes, that's right, this needs to be regulated by means of CSS, thank you.